# Identity Server 4 refresh token does not update access token with the option turned on

Tags: asp.net, .net, identityserver4

I encountered very strange behavior with Identity Server 4 running on ASP.NET Web API.
My refresh token still refreshes only the duration of my access token without its claims. And the problem persists even with **UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true** and I am wondering what am I doing wrong.
I even tried to turn off the Re-Usage of the Refresh token - because I thought maybe they are stored inside the IS4 in form of pairs. And maybe using the same refresh token would produce the same access token. But I turned it off, tested it and still my refresh token does not do the job.

I have the following configuration of a client:

```
new Client
           {
            ClientId = "AngularClient",
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 60,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 259200,
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
            AllowedCorsOrigins = new []
            {
                "http://localhost:4200",
                "https://localhost:7193"
            }
```

Can anyone say what might be the problem here?

Comment: Does the access token contains the desired claims when you initial login but not after using the refresh token?

Comment: Yes. If I create manually an access token for User X. Then try update his claims. If I refresh and retrieve acess token - the claims are not updated. If I manually create new access token (without refresh token) the claims ARE updated.